# Hybris Flexiquery : Column ambiguously defined

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to fire the below query using pagedFlexibleSearchService.

```
SELECT {u: PK}, {a: PK} FROM { User AS u}, {Address AS a} WHERE {u: PK} = {a: owner}
```

I am configuring flexibleSearchQuery to return the following item types:

```
flexiQuery.setResultClassList(UserModel.class,String.class));
```

I am returning User model and AddressModel pk as a string.

The problem is when I am firing this query through java code, it throws SQLException - column ambiguously defined. I noticed the converted query containing `SELECT * FROM (SELECT....) rownum <10`.
However, when I am firing the same flexiquery in HAC, it executes perfectly fine.

Could someone please let me know what the issue could be?

Regards,
Farhan

Comment: Why did you set String? It should be `flexiQuery.setResultClassList(UserModel.class,AddressModel.class));`, the address PK is mapped on AddressModel.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a lot more easy to do the flexible search only for the users(Customers):

```
SELECT {u: PK} FROM { User AS u}
```

And after that, in java code to get each user's list of addresses:

```
List<UserModel> users=getUsers();
//first user's list of addresses
Collection<AddressModel> addresses = users.get(0).getAddresses();
//the first address's(of the first user) 
PK pk = addresses.iterator().next().getPk();
```

The getUsers method:

```
private List<UserModel> getUsers() {
    FlexibleSearchQuery query = new FlexibleSearchQuery("SELECT {u: PK} FROM { User AS u}");
    return  (List) getFlexibleSearchService().search(query).getResult();
}
```

Comment: I have mentioned only 2 models in the above query, but I am actually firing query on 4 models that can't be fetched from java code also because of the many conditions, its better to fire a query with 4 models.